# Send only a few entries of JSON array

Tags: arrays, json

Is it possible to send only certain entries of a JSON array?

I have a JSON object defined by the following schema:

```
"LineGroup": {
    "type": "array",
    "description": "Line group active",
    "items": {
        "type": "boolean"
    },
    "maxItems": 10
}
```

At the beginning all entries are send. But later on only some entries are changed and only these new values must be updated.

If my syntax at the beginning when I send the full array is:

```
[{"LineGroup":"False"},{"LineGroup":"True"},...,{"LineGroup":"True"}]
```

What will be the syntax to only send 1 or 2 entries that have changed in this array? Do I need to resend the whole array?

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could use json patch to update the original json object:

http://jsonpatch.com/

The cool thing is that the patch documents themselves are also json documents.